# How to merge data from 2 tables including fields that have no match

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following MySQL statement:

```
SELECT gls.id AS glid, gls.gl, gls.name AS gl_name, requests.costCenter, budgets.total as totalBudgeted,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 1 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap1, 
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 2 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap2,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 3 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap3,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 4 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap4,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 5 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap5,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 6 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap6,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 7 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap7,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 8 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap8,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 9 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap9,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 10 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap10,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 11 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap11,
                    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN requests.ap = 12 THEN totalCost ELSE 0 END), 2) AS ap12 
                FROM gls
                    LEFT JOIN requests ON requests.glid = gls.id 
                    LEFT JOIN budgets ON budgets.gl = gls.id AND budgets.costCenter = 2
                WHERE requests.status = 'approved' AND requests.costCenter = 2
                    GROUP BY gls.id
```

My problem is that when I run the query, I only get the "gl"s that have requests linked to them. "gl"s with no corresponding entry in the requests table are not displayed.

I tried a few permutations of JOINS, but nothing seems to work. It's obvious to me that the limiting factor is the `LEFT JOIN requests ON requests.glid = gls.id` which is preventing all of the GLs to be displayed but as far as I can see, a LEFT JOIN should keep ALL of the GL tables values, and add only the corresponding REQUESTS values.

For privacy reasons I can't display any data, but I can try to summarize it:

in the gls table there are 30 rows,

In the requests table, there could be any number of rows but each one has a foreign key linking them to a row in the gls table. Basically, my query should give me a table of ALL the gls, and tag on information from corresponding requests next to it.

Also, I have a feeling someone here will be able to clean this query up and make it much, much shorter.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about LEFT JOIN. The issue is your WHERE:

```
WHERE requests.status = 'approved' AND requests.costCenter = 2
```

This filters out all rows where there is no request.

Instead you want to move that condition to the JOIN:

```
LEFT JOIN requests 
  ON requests.glid = gls.id 
 AND requests.status = 'approved' AND requests.costCenter = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and thanks for the answer. Will accept as soon as i can. Cheers! Now I can stop the overtime.